# unable to define a horizental form using Bootstrap v2.0.4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application and i am using Bootstrap v2.0.4. now i want to show a list of drop-down lists beside each other . so i define the following :-

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">Customer </label> @Html.DropDownList("CustomerList", (SelectList)ViewBag.Customers, "<< All Customers >>",new {@class = "controls"})
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">Status </label> @Html.DropDownList("StatuesList", (SelectList)ViewBag.OrderStatus, "<< All Statutes >>",new {@class = "controls"})
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">Type </label>   @Html.DropDownList("TypeList", (SelectList)ViewBag.OrderTypes, "<< All Types >>",new {@class = "controls"})
  </div>
   <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">Category </label> @Html.DropDownList("CommissionList",  (SelectList)ViewBag.CommissionTypes, "<< All Commission Types >>",new {@class = "controls"}) <img src="~/Content/sortloading.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress" /> 
  </div>
</form>
<br />
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" >Show   </label>    @Html.DropDownList("FilterSize1", new SelectList(ViewBag.PagedSizeOptions, "Value", "Text",Model.PageSize ), new { @class = "controls"}) <img src="~/Content/sortloading.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress1" /> <label >Per Page   </label>
 </div>
</form>
```

but i got the following result , where the dropdownlists rendered under each other as follow:-

[image]

here is the related HTML as per the firbug tool:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce how to force my dropdown lists to expand horizontally ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

now i tried modifying my code as follow where i added `control-group form-inline` & `form-horizontal form-inline` ,, but the drop-down lists did not adjust horizontally ..

so i added the following class inside my view:-

```
 .form-horizontal .control-group {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and i keep my code as follow:-

```
 <form class="form-horizontal ">
  <div class="control-group ">
   <label class="control-label">Customer </label> @Html.DropDownList("CustomerList", (SelectList)ViewBag.Customers, "<< All Customers >>",new {@class = "controls"})
  </div>
  <div class="control-group ">
   <label class="control-label">Status </label> @Html.DropDownList("StatuesList", (SelectList)ViewBag.OrderStatus, "<< All Statutes >>",new {@class = "controls"})
  </div>
  <div class="control-group ">
   <label class="control-label">Type </label>   @Html.DropDownList("TypeList", (SelectList)ViewBag.OrderTypes, "<< All Types >>",new {@class = "controls"})
  </div>
   <div class="control-group ">
   <label class="control-label">Category </label> @Html.DropDownList("CommissionList",  (SelectList)ViewBag.CommissionTypes, "<< All Commission Types >>",new {@class = "controls"}) <img src="~/Content/sortloading.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress" /> 
  </div>
</form>
<br />
<form class="form-horizontal ">
  <div class="control-group ">
<label class="control-label" >Show   </label>    @Html.DropDownList("FilterSize1", new SelectList(ViewBag.PagedSizeOptions, "Value", "Text",Model.PageSize ), new { @class = "controls"}) <img src="~/Content/sortloading.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress1" /> <label >Per Page   </label>
 </div>
</form>
```

now the fields were aligned horizontally ,, but i got a lot of spaces between the fields (mainly between the label and the dropdown list), as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on the following:-

- when i added the `form-inline` class to my classes; `control-group form-inline` & `form-horizontal form-inline` .. why my fields did not aligned horizontally ?
- when i define the following :-

  .form-horizontal .control-group {
    display: inline-block;
  }

the fields were aligned horizontally ,, but i got a lot of spaces between the label and the drodown,, so is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: inline-block` to your `control-group` class. Like so:

```
.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

to limit this to just the ones within the `form-horizontal`, do this:

```
.form-horizontal .control-group {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

this will make the elements stack horizontally, rather than vertically.

#### Demo:

```css
.form-horizontal .control-group {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Customer</label>
    <select>
      <option value="all">All customers</option>
      <option value="a">Customer A</option>
      <option value="b">Customer B</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Status</label>
    <select>
      <option value="all">All statuses</option>
      <option value="a">Status A</option>
      <option value="b">Status B</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, will try this ,, but i am not sure why the class definition is not already defined inside bootstrap templete ? is this the case in bootstrap 2 ???

Comment: if you want a bootstrap class you can add the class `form-inline` instead. It does the same thing.

Comment: where do i need to add it? instead of .form-horizontal & .control-group OR in addition to them ?

Comment: yes add it so that you have `control-group form-inline`

Comment: your code partially work in my case.. can you check my edit to see my latest result .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

add the class form-inline to your form classes.

Comment: but why this class definition is not already defined inside the bootstrap template?? i do not want to start adding rules against the bootstrap template ,, but i want to restrict with what already provided by bootstrap ..so is there a way to show horizontal form inside bootstrap 2 ?

Comment: your code partially work in my case.. can you check my edit to see my latest result .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

See below a basic form template for bootstrap.  The horizontal layout is determined by the "row" div 
the input box layout here would look like this

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group group-sm">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First Name">
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group group-sm">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group group-sm">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email Address">
  </div>
</form>
```

[image: Layout]

Comment: but i do not want to define these col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 . i want to comply with bootstrap built-in classes for  horizontal forms

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic  these are css styles and they are implemented in bootstrap by default. take a look see at this link